Troubleshooting agarose gel electrophoresis - Loading dye and DNA samples moving in opposite directions
The students of my Genetics class and I (instructor) are experiencing a systematic issue with our agarose gel electrophoreses which we cannot explain. We are looking for ideas that could explain our observations, so that we can resolve this issue (or these issues, in case multiple overlapping issues are present).
We are conducting our agarose gel elctrophoreses under the following conditions:

Agarose gel: 1% agarose gel (made with agarose I and fresh 1X TAE buffer of pH=8)
Sample-loading dye-ethidium bromide mixture: 5 uL of DNA sample (DNA quantity > 100ng/uL as confirmed via NanoDrop) + 2 uL loading dye + 2 uL ethidium bromide (1:10 dilution)
Gel rig: negative electrode (black cable) connected to top of rig, positive electrode (red cable) connected to bottom of rig (see image); filled with 1X TAE buffer; agarose gel positioned such that gel wells near top of rig
Run conditions: 30 minutes at 80 V, then visualization under UV light
IMPORTANT: The first lane of the gel is loaded with a gene ruler-loading dye-ethidium bromide mixture: 3 uL of 'GeneRuler 100bp' + 2 uL loading dye + 2 uL ethidium bromide (1:10 dilution)

We have run these conditions on different gel rigs and varied the run time (20-40 min.), the buffer (either TAE or TBE buffer), and the DNA intercalating substance (either ethidium bromide or SYBRsafe), yet the result is always one of the following unsatisfactory results:

no bands whatsoever
bands that are "stuck" in the gel well (i.e., only the gel wells are illuminated by the ethidium bromide under UV light)
bands that run in the "wrong" direction (towards the negative electrode!; see image)

Two important observations:

In all attempts, the loading dye has always moved in the expected direction (i.e., toward the positive electrode), whereas the DNA fragments (if present) have not

Please note that a low DNA concentration in the sample cannot be the reason for missing bands, as none of the commercial DNA ladder (Gene Ruler 100bp) bands are visible either.


Loaded samples: The lanes in the following images represent (from left to right):

Gene Ruler 100bp
DNA sample (fresh PCR product; expected lane at 219 bp)
DNA sample (fresh PCR product; expected lanes at 175 bp and 44 bp)
empty
empty
DNA sample (fresh PCR product; expected lane at 219 bp)
empty
empty

 


Edit 1: A potential clue to resolving this issue may reside in the fact that the filled wells of the agarose gels still "light up" under UV light within the first 10 minutes of running the gel, as displayed below (for a different sample). However, after another 10-20 minutes, any indication of these bands are either gone or represent blobs that migrated into the "wrong" direction.


Edit 2 (Nov-07-2024): My students and I followed the advice given to us in the comments sections and prepared an agarose gel electrophoresis with entirely fresh materials: fresh PCR product, fresh agarose gel, fresh SYBRsafe, and fresh TAE buffer in dish-washer clean glassware. The SYBRsafe was added when making the agarose gel at a concentration of 10 ug SYBRsafe per mL molten agarose. The result of that electrophoresis is just as before: the DNA ladder migrates the "wrong" direction (towards the negative electrode; see lane 1), whereas the PCR product is "stuck" in the gel well (lane 7).


How did you prepare the sample, and what is its expected size? The fact that you can't see the ladder (in either direction) indicates that there's something wrong with your set-up. I would suspect that the blobs at the top are not DNA. I'd suspect DNA degradation first off.

@bob1 I have added the relevant details to the post. What do you mean by "DNA degradation"? Lane 1 represents a fresh commercial DNA ladder, lanes 2, 3, and 6 fresh PCR products. Why would any of those be degraded, not least in multiple attempts spread out over multiple days?

First of all: Are you absolutely sure that your PCR worked? When you measure the reaction, unincorporated oligos will give you a signal. I would at least clean up one reaction. Are there residual salts in your chamber? These can disturb. Have you tried either staining the gel afterwards or adding the EtBr to the gel mix? I never mixed it into the sample.

@Chris Yes, I am certain that the PCRs worked. Not only have we been conducting very different sets of PCR amplifications (sometimes targeting smaller amplicons, sometimes longer amplicons), we also see clear changes in the DNA concentrations before and after the PCRs using both the NanoDrop (not precise in these cases) and the Qubit 4.0 (better in these cases). And even in the off-chance that all our PCRs failed, we should at least see the commercial DNA ladder after gel electrophoresis. Yet we don't!

@Chris Yes, we tried adding either the ethidium bromide or the SYBRsafe into the liquid agarose (once it cooled down but before it hardened) or into the sample that was loaded onto the gel. It did not change the outcome of a lack of bands.

@MichaelGruenstaeudl By degradation I mean that your gel component(s) might have become contaminated with DNase somehow. Often this is from bacterial residues in unclean glassware or even in your pipettes. It might be in your loading dye. In your last gel photo (the one with the wells lighting up) is it the same sample order as in the other photos? Also, the movement of the samples in that photo indicates them going in the right direction....

@bob1 If DNase contamination were the case, it must have occurred in very different pipettes, gel rigs, and loading dye samples; the likelihood of that is very, very low.  While samples of the photo posted under "Edit1" are not the same as the ones posted before, they illustrate a common observation among our unsuccessful gels: that the gel wells almost always "light up" upon being loaded, at least initially. However, after 20-40 min electrophoresis runtime, the anticipated bands are nowhere to be seen.

Try including EtBr in the gel and running buffer. Alternatively, soak the gel in EtBr/TAE after the run. EtBr is positively charged and migrates in the opposite direction of DNA if not intercalated. It also binds DNA with a relatively low affinity, so EtBr added in the loading buffer only could be stripped off during the run.

Try running a higher percentage gel - 1% is too low to resolve those sizes properly, Aim for closer to 2%. Not that you shouldn't see bands, just that bands will be indistinct at those sizes, which make them harder to see. The upper bands on the ladder will be OK at 1%. The GeneRuler documentation recommends 1.7%. Degradation of samples and ladders is a common effect in labs. Don't rule it out! Get a new un-opened ladder, make a fresh gel with fresh TAE etc. Load old ladder and new. Run the gel.

In my experience (and they are something I set up regularly), taught labs are all set up from stocks - students are given aliquots of that stock. If one stock is contaminated/off, then that can cause a lab-wide issue. It might not be the pipettes (though I have seen it on autoclaved batches of tips - autoclave had been used for a wasteload of a DNase producing bacteria immediately beforehand), but it could be the glassware used to prepare the TAE stock, or the agarose, or even the EtBr or loading dye. Talk to the tech who set it up and ask for new stocks of everything, and test systematically.

@bob1 Thank you for your suggestions. Since I do not have a lab tech (small teaching college), I have my students make their own buffers fresh at the beginning of every semester. If DNase-contaminated buffer were the reason for our problems, then it must have occurred in the Tris-base powder or the EDTA powder, as multiple independent students experience the same contamination. I consider this unlikely. Similarly, glassware is washed in the dishwasher (using LabConoco's LabSolutions non-foaming power detergent as detergent) and pipette tips autoclaved (or re-autoclaved) before every lab.

@bob1 We have already tested gels with slight deviations from an 1% agarose content (e.g., a 2% agarose gel), yet those gels result in exactly the same problem: neither the samples nor the DNA ladder are visible after 10 minutes of electrophoresis runtime. It all circles back to the same question: What happens at the beginning of or during the gel electrophoresis? Something at that moment either degrades the DNA or removes the EtBr/SYBRsafe from the DNA.

@bob1 I will say, however, that all pipettes themselves are routinely shared with the microbiology students (who do numerous experiments on live bacteria). The insides of those pipettes have not been cleaned in recent memory. Whatever is growing inside of these pipettes is anybody's guess.

@MichaelGruenstaeudl Try loading intact genomic DNA or plasmid of known concentration. Should get a high MW smear (genomic) or band(s) for plasmid. If you load enough you should be able to see if this migrates out of the well and/or degrades over time or if it gets stuck; monitor every 5 min or so. Add EtBr to the running buffer or gel to prevent EtBr shadow; I think those blobs in your first gel are EtBr. Load your mix alone to confirm. I don't think it'll take the DNA with it. I use EtBr at 10 ug/ml (1:1000) in gel or buffer - is that similar to your 1:10?

@bob1 My students and I followed your suggestions, yet received the same weird pattern: the DNA ladder migrates the "wrong" direction (towards the negative electrode), whereas the PCR product is "stuck" in the gel well (lane 7). Please see the gel image under 'Edit 2 (Nov-07-2024)' above.

@Chris My students and I followed your suggestion and mixed the SYBRsafe into the agarose gel when preparing it, yet our results were as always: the DNA ladder migrates the "wrong" direction (towards the negative electrode), whereas the PCR product is "stuck" in the gel well (lane 7). Please see the gel image under 'Edit 2 (Nov-07-2024)' above.

@MichaelGruenstaeudl Wow, never seen both directions before. Ionic problems would be my first thought. pH of 8 as in your question is ~correct, so it shouldn't be that. You sometimes see these sorts of effects if there is a problem in the amount of ions in one of the solutions added - e.g. added MgCl2 instead of H2O in PCR. I'd guess that with longer run time, the PCR product would start to migrate in the wrong direction too, currently balanced by the ions in the reaction. Is the ladder in the same loading dye as the samples?

@MichaelGruenstaeudl That's really weird and something I have never seen (and having teached undergrad molecular biology courses I have seen a lot of errors). It would mean for some reasons that your marker is charged wrongly. Do you have the chance to get another marker which is known to have run in the right direction in the past?
